# Sci-fi book about a girl who gains light powers from an alien boy who tried to save her from an enemy alien race that emits darkness

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, powers

I read this book some time ago and can't seem to find or remember the name of it.

It's about a girl who gets powers from an alien boy, I think he tried to save her from an enemy alien race that emitted darkness where he emits light. I remember the government being onto it and controlling the aliens and I remember her glowing after getting  powers. There was this scene in a forest where the girl fights with those dark aliens and takes out a few satellites with light powers.

Hope this makes sense. English is not my first language so I apologize for any mistakes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?